# how to Check uncheck of a radio button?

Tags: ios, image, uibutton

I am using an image in a button to make the button radio button. I can check it by changing image but I can't uncheck it. Please help me. I am using this code in button action

```
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: You do it wrong way. Assign image for selected state also, and then use button.selected = !button.selected;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have store in your viewController the state of the button...

```
BOOL checked;

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    checked = YES;  //Set depending on your initial state
}

-(IBACtion)pressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    checked = !checked;
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:((checked) ? @"check2.png" : @"NOTCHECKEDIMAGE.png")] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: What a compile error? It would helot to know what the error is

Comment: implicit conversion of'BOOL'(aka 'bool') to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC.

Comment: but there is a problem .. at the very first time when i click on the button it is in uncheck state but after it work fine.

Comment: Have you set the initial value of `checked` to be `NO` ?

Comment: can u please help in my another question-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714529/implement-switch-case-in-button-action

Comment: Use selected instead of checked.